# Is there any way to get the values of sequence generator transformation for each workflow?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I want to have a report about sequence generator transformation values of every workflow. One way is to manually open every session of workflows, go to sequence generator and note down the values.

So, is there any shortcut for doing this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Informatica metadatabase to get all current values of all seq generators.
Here is the SQL  you can use -
This query will give you folder, parent folder, mapping name, seq gen name, and current value.

```
SELECT 
b.SUBJECT_AREA folder_name, b.PARENT_SUBJECT_AREA parent_folder_name,
m.MAPPING_NAME,
a.attr_value AS current_value , b.WIDGET_NAME AS Transformation_name
FROM rep_widget_attr a , REP_ALL_TRANSFORMS b, REP_ALL_MAPPINGS m 
WHERE a.attr_id=4
AND a.widget_id IN (SELECT widget_id FROM REP_ALL_TRANSFORMS WHERE widget_type_name LIKE 'Sequence')
AND a.widget_id=b.widget_id
and b.MAPPING_ID=m.MAPPING_ID
```

Comment: That query does the job, but misses some explanations... You can find more in the documentation https://docs.informatica.com/data-integration/powercenter/10-2/repository-guide/using-metadata-exchange--mx--views.html

Comment: sorry, i added explanation of my SQL. Above link just gives repo tables, you still need to join them to create what you need